# Help understand a simple C code for an atmega16 project

Tags: avr, atmega, c

I just got started with AVR , and I am building a Lan tester for a project

My hardware part is done, basically for the send pins I used port A , from A0 to A7 and for the Receiver port C when the cable is inserted in the RJ jack a signal should be sent and compared to some existing vectors , the result of the vector comparison is sent to port B and a led corresponding to the cable type should turn on

here is the code,I commented the parts that I cant understand, please help me with them
the most part the confused me is the ">>" i know it shifts but what exactly 
why do we return 0 then 1 or the opposite
and why the status=0 ?

```
#define DSEND               DDRA
#define DRECEIVE            DDRC
#define DLED                DDRD
#define ISEND               PINA
#define IRECEIVE            PINC
#define ILED                PIND
#define OSEND               PORTA
#define ORECEIVE            PORTC
#define OLED                PORTD

// the cabels types vectors 
int STRAIGHT[8]=        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int CROSS_T568A[8]=     {3, 6, 1, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5 };
int CROSS_T568B[8]=     {3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8 };
int ROLLOVER[8]=        {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

// why do we need to start with zeros ? and why is the status 0 ? 
 int TEST[8]=       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

 int status = 0;

//why retrun i+1? 
 int getActiveBit(int x) {
int i;
for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    if(bit_is_set(x, i))
        return i + 1;
return 0;
  }

  // comparing the two vectors 
  // but why return 0 this time ?
  int compare(int *a, int *b) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    if(a[i]!=b[i])
        return 0;
return 1;
}

//setting the status, what status exactly
 void setStatus(int value) {
status = value;
}

 //get the status 
int getStatus() {
return status;
}

   //display the cable type with a corresponding led each type with a led
  // what is this << I know it shift but what 
   void displayMessage() {
if(compare(TEST, STRAIGHT))
    OLED |= 1<<1;
else if(compare(TEST, CROSS_T568A))
    OLED |= 1<<4;
else if(compare(TEST, CROSS_T568B))
    OLED |= 1<<5;
else if(compare(TEST, ROLLOVER))
    OLED |= 1<<6;
else 
    OLED |= 1<<0;
}

//check if the cable is inserted
int isCableInserted() {
int i, r;
for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
    OSEND = 1<<i;
    r = IRECEIVE;

    if(getActiveBit(r) != 0) {
        OSEND=0x00;
        return 1;
    }
}
OSEND = 0x00;
return 0;
  }

  int main() {  
  //why so many variables
    int i, r, k;

DSEND = 0xFF;
DRECEIVE = 0x00;
DLED = 0xFF;


do {
    if(isCableInserted()) {

        OLED = 0x00;
        OLED |= (1<<6);
        OLED |= (1<<5);
        OLED |= (1<<4);
        OLED |= (1<<1);

        for(i=0; i<8; i++) {

            OSEND = 1<<(7-i);
            for(k=0;k<10;k++)
                _delay_ms(100);
            //_delay_ms(1000);

            // what is this exactly ?
            r = IRECEIVE;

            // memorise
            TEST[i] = 8-getActiveBit(r)+1;


            if(TEST[i] != 0) {

                //if at least one wire is connected the cable is connected
                if(getStatus() == 0)
                    setStatus(1);
            } 

            for(k=0;k<2;k++)
                _delay_ms(100);
            //_delay_ms(200);
        }


        OSEND=0x00;

        if(getStatus() == 1) {
            OLED=0x00;
            displayMessage();
            for(k=0;k<30;k++)
                _delay_ms(100);
            //_delay_ms(3000);
            setStatus(0);
        }

    }
    else{
        //the error led not insterted or defected
        OLED = 0x01;
        for(k=0;k<30;k++)
            _delay_ms(100);
        //_delay_ms(3000);
    }
} while(1);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a fix my code question.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really answer many of the specific questions about what the pieces of your code do, but I'll explain the bit shifting (the `1 << n` lines).

You can represent 1 as the 8 bit binary number `0000 0001`. The `<<` operator takes all of the bits and moves them 1 spots to the right, throwing out the MSB and putting a 0 on the LSB. That means that `1 << 3 = 0000 1000`. If you label the bits 0 through 7, we now have a number where the only high bit is in position 3.

This is useful for working with the 8 separate pins in your PORTA, PORTB, etc registers. For example, if you want to set pins 0, 2, and 5 high, you want to write

`PORTD = 0010 0101`

but it's much easier to quickly read and edit a line that uses the OR operator `|`, making your code look like

`PORTD = 1<<5 | 1<<2 | 1<<0`

which clearly says "set bits 0, 2, and 5 high".

(PS: fix your indenting! yuck!)